# Where to go next if my first move reveals a number?

Tags: minesweeper

I started a game of Minesweeper, and it ended pretty unspectacularly:

[image: Game over after revealing two squares]

I clicked near the center of the board, revealing a '1'. I then clicked a square next to the 1, revealing the mine.

Is there anything I *could've* done in such a situation to improve my chances? Is it just down to luck?

Comment: You posted this at an interesting time - we have an on going [meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16051/how-should-we-handle-questions-asking-how-to-solve-a-specific-minesweeper-board) about how to handle these minesweeper questions... I can tell you that your answer lies [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/166558/163757).

Comment: @TimmyJim Hmmm...I'm not the biggest fan of "hope and pray", but I guess that's ultimately what Minesweeper is all about. Thanks for the link. You can close it as a duplicate as well, since that's pretty much a duplicate.

Comment: In this case, yup! You could only technically make a guess. You stood a really good chance of surviving, but as luck would have it... you didn't make it. That's got to be the worse way to lose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The odds of hitting that mine were 1/8 ≈ 13%. The odds of hitting a mine anywhere else on the board were 98/471 ≈ 21%.

So you made the right choice, and got unlucky.  That's Minesweeper.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 1/8 as there are 8 squares around the "1"?

Comment: @SkrewEverything: Facepalmed and fixed, thanks!

Comment: Basically, there is no 'win every time' strategy in Minesweeper because of this. You can be unlucky and just click a mine in the first few moves, nothing to do about it because the board is decided before your first click. It doesn't change to make sure you don't get a mine in your first 2-3 clicks.

Comment: @Fredy31: I believe some versions of Minesweeper detect the case where the very first square clicked is a mine, and move the mine to the top-left square if this happens. So I guess the moral there is "don't guess the top-left square if you have to guess."